# Codeigniter 2.0.2 form validation set_rules custom error message not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-validation

I'm trying to add a custom error message on for codeigniter form validation.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('month', 'Month', 'trim|required', array('required' => 'You need to supply period starting month'));
```

But unfortunately I'm still getting

> The Month field is required.

error message.

My ci version is **2.0.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CI 2, you need to set the custom error messages like below:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
```

And as your requirement this may work,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('month', 'period starting month', 'trim|required');

$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'You need to supply %s');
```

Please see the [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors)

`set_rules` does **not set the validation messages** in the **version** you are using.